# jQuery AJAX loop click events

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, events, click

We have a simple jQuery HTML page, that loads AJAX data.

Now, we are having trouble working with the items in the iteration.

There is a `<li>` element in the $.each() loop, providing items held in database. We need to be able to click on these items in the loop, and pass their ID values over to another AJAX call.

Since they items are being iterated, we can not work with them. Outside of the loop, it works perfectly as expected.  We think we need to "bind events", but nothing we do works in this case.   Any help really appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/website/ajax',
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var addlink = '+ Add';
                        var itemstore = '';
                        
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            let badgeitem = item.badge.split('.')[0].replace(/^\w/, (badge) => badge.toUpperCase());
                            itemstore += '<li><a href="#"><img title="' + item.descr + '" style="width:65px;height:65px" src="/images/newsfeed/badges/' + item.badge + '" /></a>' + badgeitem + '</li>';    
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

We have tried the following solution

```
let storedData = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    storedData[key] = { "dataname":data[key].item.badge } 
}
```

But unable get it working. **We need JSON response ID (preferably) passed over from each unique item clicked**.

A alert dialog with the ID would be perfect (item.id).

Full page source:

```
<body>
    
<div class="launcher">
    <div class="app-launcher">
      <div class="apps">
        <ul class="first-set"></ul>
        <a href="#" class="more">More</a>
        <ul class="second-set hide">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-html5 fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linux fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-css3 fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dropbox fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></i></a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- load badges -->
<div style="display:inline;float:left">
    <div id="badge-users"></div>
</div>

<!-- badge browse -->
<div style="display:inline;float:left" id="badge-store">Loading...</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var scroll = false;
    var launcherMaxHeight = 100;
    var launcherMinHeight = 100;

    $('.app-launcher').hide();

    // Mousewheel event handler to detect whether user has scrolled over the container
    $('.apps').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            // Scrolling up
        } else {
            // Scrolling down
            if (!scroll) {
                $(".second-set").show();
                $('.apps').css({
                    height: launcherMinHeight
                }).addClass('overflow');
                scroll = true;
                $(this).scrollTop(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
            }
        }
    });

    // Scroll event to detect that scrollbar reached top of the container
    $('.apps').scroll(function () {
        var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (pos == 0) {
            scroll = false;
            $('.apps').css({
                height: launcherMaxHeight
            }).removeClass('overflow');
            $(".second-set").hide();
        }
    });

    // Click event handler to show more apps
    $('.apps .more').click(function () {
        $(".second-set").show();
        $(".apps").animate({
            scrollTop: $('.apps')[0].scrollHeight
        }).css({
            height: 296
        }).addClass('overflow');
    });

    // Click event handler to toggle dropdown
    $("li").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert('Item selected. Send to AJAX.');
        $(".app-launcher").toggle();
    });

    // Click event handler to toggle dropdown
    $("#badge-store").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".app-launcher").toggle();
    });

    // Prevent hiding on click inside app launcher
    $('.app-launcher').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
        //Hide the launcher if visible
        $('.app-launcher').hide();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax_newsfeed_badges.php?id=454',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        success: function (res) {
            res.forEach((element, i) => {
                data = {
                    badgeinfo: element['info'],
                    badge: element['badge'],
                    avatars: element.avatars
                }
                let avatars = [];

                // Users + badges already awarded
                data.avatars.forEach(avatar => {
                    avatars.push('<span class="tooltip-badge" title="' + data.badgeinfo + '" style="position:relative;margin-right:-10px;z-index:95000"><img src="/images/newsfeed/badges/' + data.badge + '" /></span><a href="/user/?id=' + avatar.userid + '"><img itemprop="image" class="responsive-img" style="width:25px;height:25px;margin-right:5px;border-radius:50%" src="/' + avatar.avatar_thumb + '" /></a></span>');
                });
                avatars.forEach(avatar => {
                    $('#badge-users').append(avatar);
                });

                // Browse available badges
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/website/ajax',
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var addlink = '+ Add';
                        var itemstore = '';
                        
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            let badgeitem = item.badge.split('.')[0].replace(/^\w/, (badge) => badge.toUpperCase());
                            itemstore += '<li data-name="dsf"><a href="#"><img title="' + item.descr + '" style="width:65px;height:65px" src="/images/newsfeed/badges/' + item.badge + '" /></a>' + badgeitem + '</li>';    
                        });

                        $("#badge-store").html(addlink);
                        $(".first-set").html(itemstore);
                    }
                });
            });

            $('.tooltip-badge').tooltipster({
                animation: 'grow',
                delay: 200,
                theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

JSON data (url: '/website/ajax')

```
[{"badge":"ghost.png","descr":"Sends a ghostly vibe","id":"1"},{"badge":"bitcoin.png","descr":"Mining this post?!","id":"2"}]
```

Comment: Hi, you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n80hwabo/) ?

Comment: Yes!! exactly! Thank you so much for taking the time on this Swati, I appreciate that very much! +1

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted by **Swati** was the answer. This is the full solution to the original question.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/ajax_test.php',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                var itemstore = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    let badgeitem = item.badge.split('.')[0].replace(/^\w/, (badge) => badge.toUpperCase());
                    itemstore += '<li data-id="' + item.id + '" data-name="' + item.badge + '"><img title="' + item.descr + '" style="width:65px;height:65px" src="/images/newsfeed/badges/' + item.badge + '" />' + badgeitem + '</li>';
                });
                $('#badge-store').html('+ Add');
                $('.first-set').html(itemstore);

                var selected = false;
                $('.first-set').on('click', 'li', function () {
                    if (selected == false) {
                        selected = true;
                    } else {
                        selected = false;
                    }
                    if (selected) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/website/ajax',
                            data: {
                                badge_id: $(this).data('id'),
                                badge_name: $(this).data('name'),
                                post_id: 454,
                                user_id: 1
                            },
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                alert('POST ajax started');
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert('Badge submitted successfully.');
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert('Error');
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // no action
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

So it was a matter of adding data attributes to the iterated `<li>` element, and after that loop (outside, after code block), call `$(this).data('id')` while "id" is the `data-**key**` (key being a item within your AJAX loop).

Once applied, as shown.. you can proceed to the POST process based on the data-element found and pass those values over (like a INSERT or UPDATE statement in your endpoint script - AJAX url).

Answer (score 0):

As the `li` elements are added to the DOM after the page loads you can use a delegated event handler bound to a common parent element to handle the click action. In addition you can use a `data` attribute to hold the value of the `id` property and retrieve it within that click handler, something like this:

```js
// inside AJAX callback:
let itemstore = data.forEach(item => {
  let badgeitem = item.badge.split('.')[0].replace(/^\w/, (badge) => badge.toUpperCase());
  return `<li><a href="#" data-id="${item.id}"><img title="${item.descr}" src="/images/newsfeed/badges/${item.badge}" /></a>${badgeitem}</li>`;
}
$('#parent').append(itemstore);

// outside AJAX callback:
$('#parent').on('click', 'li a', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = $(e.target).data('id');

  console.log(id);
});
```

Note that I removed the inline `style` from the `li` HTML - that should be placed in an external stylesheet instead of within the HTML, within the JS.

Comment: I followed this with exact instructions, front and back and tested for an hour. I have broken JS, and no JSON response. No output from any variable, alert or console. I remove the first 'let' block and page is restored, resulting in original dilemma.

Comment: Could you please update the question to include the HTML of the page and also the content returned to `data` in your AJAX request.

Comment: This solution was not at all the answer to the question, and did not work with many extensive trials. Please see "answered question" by myself.

Comment: The answer you posted is the exact same pattern as I used above. The only real difference is that you put the `data` attribute on the `li` element instead of the `a`, which you seem to have remove completely.

Comment: The problem was entirely ```let itemstore = data.forEach(item => {
  let badgeitem = item.badge.split('.')[0].replace(/^\w/, (badge) => badge.toUpperCase());
  return `<li><a href="#" data-id="${item.id}"><img title="${item.descr}" src="/images/newsfeed/badges/${item.badge}" /></a>${badgeitem}</li>`;
}```